# Console.log is showing correct value, but the value is not rendering in React/NextJS when mapping values

Tags: reactjs, object, next.js, mapping, console.log

I am building a food ordering system and have run across a problem with rendering the cart item modifiers within the cart itself.

The console.log(mod.modName) correctly shows the name of the modifier(s) I need to render, but it won't show up in the view itself.

Also, I tested out accessing the indices of customerMods (item.customerMods[0].modName) directly, and that renders in the view as well! I don't understand what I've done wrong...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

item.customerMods array:

```
[

    {
        "modId": "OZRRMJBDKWGX27LOHMXYY6OE",
        "modPrice": 0,
        "modName": "No Mustard"
    },
    {
        "modId": "YVDOLIGNDCTOORF7FJOBF534",
        "modPrice": 25,
        "modName": "Extra Ketchup"
    }
]
```

And here's the code itself:

```
<ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>

          {item.quantity} x {item.name}  
          {item.customerMods.length > 0 ? item.customerMods.map((mod) => {
             //  {console.log(mod.modName)} -- Properly prints name of modifier
             <Text>{mod.modName}</Text>
               
          }) : "No Mods Here"}
          

          &mdash;
          <Button
            onClick={() => updateItemQuantity(item.id, item.quantity - 1) && console.log(items)}
          >
            -
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => updateItemQuantity(item.id, item.quantity + 1) && console.log(items)}
          >
            +
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)}>&times;</Button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the `item.customerMods` array?

Comment: Just added, sorry bout that.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with the `Text` component? Where does that come from? Can you share its code?

Comment: Yes, i was about to ask same, Where is that <Text> Component coming from ? is it a custom component or you accidentally declared React-Native into React ?

Comment: Ah yes, it's also missing the `return` statement, as noted in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{item.customerMods.length > 0 ? item.customerMods.map((mod) => {
             //  {console.log(mod.modName)} -- Properly prints name of modifier
             <Text>{mod.modName}</Text>
               
          }) : "No Mods Here"}
```

I don't see a `return` statement inside the `map` callback.

Comment: Nice catch @g-moniava

Comment: Thank you for catching that, my friend!